# General way for getting graphics for open source project

Tags: open-source, github

I'm in process of making an open source application for Windows. In the end I would require an icons for my app and its gui. I'm huge fan of Tango styled icons, but its pack doesn't provide all icons I need. Gnome project seems to provide ones for more mature projects that run on linux.

What is the general way, procedure for getting help in graphic assets for open source project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the general way -- if there is such a thing -- is to do a google search for "free icons".

The most commonly used set of free icons that I know about are the [silk icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/).

Comment: But, what if I wished some kind of original icon for my project . Are there any kind of open source projects that deal with these kind of things where one could ask for icon to be made? Or do I have to wait for project to be mature enough ?

Comment: @user629926 Sorry, no. There is no "open source project" where you could "ask for" an "original icon for your project." If you need something made to your own requirements, you pay for it.